# Update and add new Firebase child nodes in Firebase web app at the same time

Tags: node.js, web-applications, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been able to push new information and call it on the database but I been looking for several days now and I can't seem to find anything.

I am looking to be able to update a node that already has a value and add a new node if it doesn't. Can anyone help me with this. New to Firebase.

Thanks

code:

```
function userProfileUpdate(users) {

                newUsername = document.getElementById("newUsername");

                // Profile Update.
                var user = {
                username : newUsername.value
                };

                return firebase.database().ref().update(user);
            };
```

Comment: Adding data should be as simple as `ref.setValue({ name: "user3411711" })`. It sounds like you've tried something already. If you share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be easier to help.

Comment: Yeah I tried several methods.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What's the problem with this code? Does it run? Did you step through it in a debugger? Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: Right now it creates another node instead of updating the current one. If I structured it to be users ->uid then -> username, could it be that its not pointing to the right path?

Answer (score 3):

From your comments it seems that you want to store user information in a data structure like this:

```
users
    uid1
        userName: "Frank van Puffelen"
```

To add a specific user in this structure, you'd do:

```
function userProfileUpdate(users) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var root = firebase.database().ref();

    newUsername = document.getElementById("newUsername");

    var user = {
        username : newUsername.value
    };

    return root.child('users').child(user.uid).set(user);
};
```

## Update

To [update a specific property of a specific user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields):

```
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put("username", newUsername.value);
root.child('users').child(user.uid).updateChildren(user);
```

Or alternatively:

```
root.child('users').child(user.uid).child("username").setValue(newUsername.value);
```

Both will auto-create the location if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes the structure is correct. I get this error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined" with your updated code.

Comment: Dont know if this matters but mine is username instead of userName

Comment: Most likely `user.uid` is undefined in your scenario. Please step through the code in a debugger and check if `user` has a value and if so what its `user.uid` is. Stack Overflow is a lousy mechanism for remotely debugging things.

Comment: I think I have the wrong code overall. I want to use update not set. I have already stored the username I am just trying to get it to update. However for the items that don't exist yet like a profile pic or phone number for example I  want it to create a new value/child node.

Comment: Nodes are automatically created when you set a value to them, so you can just call `updateChildren()`.

Comment: @Frank are you sure updateChildren() will auto create the location in the key param of the map even if its a top level location on the database...top level I mean 'users' in this example. Assuming I have "users/userid/username" as my key and defined a user pojo as a value.. and this is the first db write..no previous writes with setValue() have been made

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. There could always be a bug of course, but at this point that seems unlikely. If it's not auto-creating the path for you, post a new question with a [minimal, complete example of how we can reproduce the problem you have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Frank your code took away the entire key but I did figure out with this

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var root = firebase.database().ref();

        newUsername = document.getElementById("newUsername");

        firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).update({
            username: newUsername.value
          });
```

Thanks Frank yours push me in the right direction.